# Most commonly used description use in each row for each unique id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a problem. I have articles and these articles have a unique `id`. The problem is, however, the `article` description aka `article` - this is not unique.
I would like to try changing the name of the `article` description `article` so that there is only one description left. I always want to use the `article` name that occurs most often.

I have tried something, however I don't know how to access that with `.apply(lambda x: ...` and write the most used item out to me and then set that as the name.

How can I change the description of the article so that only the most frequently mentioned article description is included?

```py
    id  article            cost
0   1   Bendge             15.30
1   1   Bendge             15.30
2   1   Bendge V2          15.30
3   1   Bendge - volumne 2 15.30
4   5   SEF                14.89
5   1   Bendge             15.30
6   2   DFH                 4.56
7   2   DFH                 4.56
8   2   DFH V2              4.56
9   2   DFH - volumne 2     4.56
10  2   DFH                 4.56
```

Code

```py
d = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'article': ['Bendge', 'Bendge', 'Bendge V2', 'Bendge - volumne 2', 'SEF', 'Bendge',
                 'DFH', 'DFH', 'DFH V2', 'DFH - volumne 2', 'DFH'],
     'cost': [15.30, 15.30, 15.30, 15.30, 14.89, 15.30,
              4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56, 4.56],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df)

df.loc[df['id'] == 1, ['id','article']].value_counts().head(1)
[OUT]
id  article
1   Bendge     3
dtype: int64

df['article'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[['id','article']].value_counts().head(1))
[OUT]
KeyError: "None of [Index(['id', 'article'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

What I want

```py
    id  article cost
0   1   Bendge  15.30
1   1   Bendge  15.30
2   1   Bendge  15.30
3   1   Bendge  15.30
4   5   SEF     14.89
5   1   Bendge  15.30
6   2   DFH      4.56
7   2   DFH      4.56
8   2   DFH      4.56
9   2   DFH      4.56
10  2   DFH      4.56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and first index:

```
df['article'] =  df.groupby('id')['article'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
print (df)
    id article   cost
0    1  Bendge  15.30
1    1  Bendge  15.30
2    1  Bendge  15.30
3    1  Bendge  15.30
4    5     SEF  14.89
5    1  Bendge  15.30
6    2     DFH   4.56
7    2     DFH   4.56
8    2     DFH   4.56
9    2     DFH   4.56
10   2     DFH   4.56
```

Another solution with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) with first value:

```
df['article'] = df.groupby('id')['article'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
print (df)
    id article   cost
0    1  Bendge  15.30
1    1  Bendge  15.30
2    1  Bendge  15.30
3    1  Bendge  15.30
4    5     SEF  14.89
5    1  Bendge  15.30
6    2     DFH   4.56
7    2     DFH   4.56
8    2     DFH   4.56
9    2     DFH   4.56
10   2     DFH   4.56
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `value_counts` to get the counts; `reset_index` + `pivot` + `idxmax` to get the most common `article` for each `id`; then `map` it back to `id`:

```py
mapping = df.value_counts(['id','article']).reset_index().pivot('id','article', 0).idxmax(axis=1)
df['article'] = df['id'].map(mapping)
```

Output:

```
    id article   cost
0    1  Bendge  15.30
1    1  Bendge  15.30
2    1  Bendge  15.30
3    1  Bendge  15.30
4    5     SEF  14.89
5    1  Bendge  15.30
6    2     DFH   4.56
7    2     DFH   4.56
8    2     DFH   4.56
9    2     DFH   4.56
10   2     DFH   4.56
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
df['article'] = df['id'].map(df.groupby('id')['article'].agg(pd.Series.mode))
```

or if a possibility of a tie:

```
df['article'] = df['id'].map(df.groupby('id')['article'].agg(lambda s: s.mode(s).iloc[0]))
```

output:

```
    id article   cost
0    1  Bendge  15.30
1    1  Bendge  15.30
2    1  Bendge  15.30
3    1  Bendge  15.30
4    5     SEF  14.89
5    1  Bendge  15.30
6    2     DFH   4.56
7    2     DFH   4.56
8    2     DFH   4.56
9    2     DFH   4.56
10   2     DFH   4.56
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#preparing data
string = """    c id  article            cost
0   1   Bendge             15.30
1   1   Bendge             15.30
2   1   BendgeV2          15.30
3   1   Bendge-volumne2 15.30
4   5   SEF                14.89
5   1   Bendge             15.30
6   2   DFH                 4.56
7   2   DFH                 4.56
8   2   DFHV2              4.56
9   2   DFH-volumne2     4.56
10  2   DFH                 4.56"""

data = [x.split() for x in string.split('\n')]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns  = data[0])

#solution
df['article'] = df.groupby('id')['article'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
```

Output:

```
c   id  article cost
0   0   1   Bendge  15.30
1   1   1   Bendge  15.30
2   2   1   Bendge  15.30
3   3   1   Bendge  15.30
4   4   5   SEF 14.89
5   5   1   Bendge  15.30
6   6   2   DFH 4.56
7   7   2   DFH 4.56
8   8   2   DFH 4.56
9   9   2   DFH 4.56
10  10  2   DFH 4.56
```

Second solution:

```
from collections import Counter
df.groupby('id')['article'].transform(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common()[0][0])
```